Getting error 'std::system_error' when executing on different machine
I tried a cpp program which uses threads on 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1265U and got no errors, when trying the same program on a container running on Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4216 CPU @ 2.10GHz I get the following error error image.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void fillRandom(float *arr, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        arr[i] = static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 10.0;
}
}
void helper(float *c,float*a,float*b,int n,int o,int i,int j)
{
            int t=0,l;
            for (l = 0; l < o; l++) {
                t += a[i * o + l] * b[l * n + j];
            }
            c[i * n + j] = t;

}
void matmul(float *a, float *b, float *c, int m, int n, int o) {
    vector <thread> threads;
    int i, j, l, t;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            threads.emplace_back(&helper,c,a,b,n,o,i,j);
        }
    }
    for(auto& th : threads){
    th.join();
}
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));

    int m = 256;
    int n = m;
    int repetitions = 10;

    float *a = new float[m * n];
    float *b = new float[m * n];
    float *c = new float[m * n];

    fillRandom(a, m * n);
    fillRandom(b, m * n);


    for (int rep = 0; rep < repetitions; ++rep) {
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        matmul(a, b, c, m, n, m);
        auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start);
        cout << "Time taken for " << rep<< "th repetition is " << duration.count() << " milliseconds" << endl;


    }

    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;

    return 0;
}

This is a mulit-threaded matrix multiply code, I am new to this, some help would be great, thanks.

Your code is not a [mcve].  Why?  Because of this: int m = atoi(argv[1]); int n = m; int repetitions = atoi(argv[2]); -- Instead of argv, simply set the variables to known values that duplicate the error, so that anyone can take the code, compile it, and run it without having to guess what values to use.

How many threads are you trying to create? Have you tried debugging?

@AlanBirtles trying to create mn threads, in this case it would 256256.

Side note with code like this it is not unlikely that you have undefined behavior somewhere (accessing data out of bounds). In C++ you really should not let arrays decay to pointers anymore. Use std::vector<float> a(m*n)  instead of new float[m*n] and void fillRandom(float*,int) should be void fillRandom(std::span<float>)... all in all I think someone has been teaching you "C" instead of "C++"

256*256 (i.e. 65536) is a lot of threads to be created in a tight loop. I wouldn't be surprised if the std::system_error is simply because it is too many. You can try to reduce the number siginificantly and check if the error disappears.

Also see: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

Since you hard coded the parameters (as requested), I removed the check for argc != 3.

Fails here https://godbolt.org/z/Gdn7b3vjo with 4 threads and 2 reps but works with 4 threads and 1 rep. Whatever it is running on says the hardware concurrency is 2.

Thanks everyone, resolved the issue by limiting no of threads to 64(which is the max threads my cpu can handle simultaneously).

You'll need to check the documentation for your os as to what the limit of the number of threads a program can create is. 65k is likely above that limit.
In general if the threads are all just doing computations (i.e. not waiting for IO operations) then creating more threads than the number of available CPU cores will decrease performance. You can use std::thread::hardware_concurrency to check the number of cores.
Something like this might work better:
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void helper(float *c,float*a,float*b,int n,int o,int row, int rows)
{
    for (int i = row; i < row + rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int t=0,l;
            for (l = 0; l < o; l++) {
                t += a[i * o + l] * b[l * n + j];
            }
            c[i * n + j] = t;
        }
    }
}
void matmul(float *a, float *b, float *c, int m, int n, int o) {
    vector <thread> threads;
    int l, t;
    int numThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    int rowsPerThread = (m + numThreads -1)/numThreads;
    for (int row = 0; row < m; row += rowsPerThread) { 
        int rows = std::min(rowsPerThread, m-row);
        threads.emplace_back(&helper,c,a,b,n,o,row, rows);
    }
    for(auto& th : threads){
        th.join();
    }
}


std::thread constructor can throw std::system_error, and

The exception may represent the error condition std::errc::resource_unavailable_try_again or another implementation-specific error condition.

You are trying to create 65536 threads, so it seems reasonable that you got "Resource temporarily unavailable". Surround your thread creation with try-catch block
try {
    threads.emplace_back(&helper,c,a,b,n,o,i,j);
}
catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "Failed to create thread on iteration: " << i << ", " << j << ", " << e.what() << "\n";
}

and see how many is "too many" on your machines.
Also note that creating N threads is not the equivalent of using SIMD instructions, e.g. when using GPU.
